# Pythagoras triples

Tags: soft-question, diophantine-equations

Regarding the parametrization of the pythagora's triples:

$x=p^2-q^2$

$y=2pq$

$z=p^2+q^2$

When $x=0,  p^2=q^2$. Given that $\gcd(p, q)=1$, is there a contradiction? Why(not)?

Comment: If you want to require $\gcd(p,q)=1$, then you certainly can't set $x=0$. The point of this formula is to parametrize Pythagorean triples with $x$, $y$, $z$ positive integers. But I'm not sure why you want to require $\gcd(p,q)=1$. For example, to get $x=12$, $y=16$, $z=20$, don't you take $p=4$ and $q=2$?

Comment: so that the triple has no common factor

Comment: by the way, I am not setting $x=0$. It just happens to be a trivial solution of $x^2+y^2=z^2$

Comment: Well, the parametrization is guaranteed to hold for x, y, and z all relatively prime (primitive Pythagorean triple) -- though as noted above, it sometimes holds in other cases -- so that's the usual starting place. E.g. 9, 12, 15 does not follow the above pattern. Now, if you try to bend the rule to allow 0s, it still more or less works: the only primitive triple 0 would actually have y=0: it is (1,0,1), so p=1, q=0 and one would have to say that 1 and 0 are relatively prime, since they have no common divisors other than 1.

Answer (score 2):

That is an incomplete parameterization.

The correct form is

$x = r(p^2-q^2),
y = 2rpq,
z = r(p^2+q^2)
$.

Also,
if $x=0$ then $y=z$.
(and $2pq=p^2+q^2$)

No contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

When we  parametrize primitive triples in the usual way, it is the $2pq$ term which is even. In the degenerate case where one of the sides is $0$, that side must be "$y$." We get  $p=1$, $q=0$, no problem.